# elementary OS heats my Dell Inspiron too much

Tags: overheat

I installed elementary OS on my Dell inspiron {2.3GHz i3, 2GB Ram}. Everything worked great but running elementary os heats my pc too much causing lots of power consumption.

Any solution for preventing from overheating.

Answer (score 3):

There are some tools that you can use  to prevent overheating on your laptop.

A good power management like TLP it's the first choice. To install from terminal :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
```

A tool to monitor and control the CPU temperature, like Thermald

```
sudo apt-get install termald
```

There are others tools like indicators (psensor, cpufreq, etc.) that you can install to better performance